# Django: How to delete child row and remove relationship from Foreign key

Tags: django

**What I want**

I have two Models. I want the following outcomes:

- When the `RecordModel` is deleted - The `BookingModel` remains the same but removes relationship to `RecordModel`.
- When the `BookingModel` is deleted - `RecordModel` is not deleted.

**What I've tried**

When trying to delete `RecordModel`. I receive error:

```py
MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cdt_dashboard`.`emissions_dashboard_bookingmodel`, CONSTRAINT `emissions_dashboard__record_id_f8312a32_fk_emissions` FOREIGN KEY (`record_id`) REFERENCES `emissions_dashboard_recordmodel` (`i)')
```

**Models**

```py
class RecordModel(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    started = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    finished = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

class BookingModel(models.Model):
    booker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    record = models.OneToOneField(RecordModel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
record = models.OneToOneField(RecordModel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

into this

```
record = models.OneToOneField(RecordModel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```